# Conditional reverse mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following mapper setup

```
public class InnerDest
{
    public int B { get; set; }
}
public class OuterDest
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public InnerDest Inner { get; set; }
}
public class FlatSource
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int? B { get; set; }
}
CreateMap<InnerDest, FlatSource>(MemberList.Source)
    .ReverseMap();
CreateMap<OuterDest, FlatSource>()
    .IncludeMember(dest => dest.Inner)
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Inner, opt => opt.Condition(source => source.B.HasValue()));
```

The idea is to make the property `Inner` optional, but it doesn't work. The property is always set regardless of the condition. Right now I do it with `AfterMap`, but I wonder if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: I think it would be easier to drop `ReverseMap` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop `ReverseMap`. Or keep it if you have to:

```
    c.CreateMap<InnerDest, FlatSource>(MemberList.Source).ReverseMap();
    c.CreateMap<OuterDest, FlatSource>()
        .IncludeMembers(s => s.Inner)
        .ReverseMap()
        .ForPath(dest => dest.Inner, opt => opt.Condition(context => context.Source.B.HasValue));
```

Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).